# Android MVVM: Where to put adapters?

Tags: android, mvvm

I'm building an Android app following the `MVVM` architecture. Where do adapters (for `recyclerView`, `viewPager`, etc) belong to?

Do `adapters` belong to `View` or `ViewModel`?

Answer (score 43):

Adapter belongs to View, but data source of Adapter belongs to ViewModel.

Answer (score 8):

If you're following MVVM architecture than , adapters are belongs to `View` not `Viewmodel`. All sub list item click events and other UI related things handled by adapter . So Adapter goes to View ..

if you want detail description , You can check this link to

[MVVM Detail](https://proandroiddev.com/mvvm-architecture-viewmodel-and-livedata-part-1-604f50cda1)

Answer (score 5):

Think on this direction..
Suppose you remove/replace your view from your code. View model should be able to reused again and can provide view data to new view. You can get answer yourself. 
Then adapter should be part of view only.